# Can we link Google Chrome to UIWebView rather than Safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser, webview

Can we link Google Chrome to UIWebView rather than Safari ?? Or is there any possibility to open my video url in google chrome on a button tap in iOS App??

Answer (score 0):

you can check this below link for webview link to chrome https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNWebViewController